# Oracle APEX subtotals and Grand Total

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-19.1

I have an APEX report and I want to have subtotals (group by column 'l_char') and Grand totals . I have achieved the subtotals by doing a page break and using the aggregate function 'add'.
[image: Subtotals_pic]

Now, I also want to show the grand subtotal at the end (eg. : it should show Total = 20000 at the end of the report).

Can somebody please help and let me know how can i achieve this.

Thanks,
Abha

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you can afford switching from interactive to **classic report**, then with an "ordinary" query:

```
select deptno, 
       ename, 
       sal
from emp
where deptno in (10, 20)
order by deptno, ename;
```

Set report's attributes:

- break formatting:

  - report sum label: Total
  - break columns: first column

Set `sal` column's properties:

- advanced - compute sum: set it to ON

Run the page; result is

[image]

Comment: Yes..That seems to work exactly in the way , i wanted...But I walso want to download the exact same report in excel i.e with thte totals an subtotals..Usually I use Apex office print to download data from an IR. But do you know how can i download the classic report in excel,with the same data and format ?

Comment: You can enable download for classic reports (it is in its attributes), but - it won't download any kind of *formatting* (totals, grand totals) ... Maybe it is possible, but I wouldn't know how to do that, sorry.

Comment: yes I tried with download for classic report, but it didn't download any of the downloading...Anyway, thanks for your help..I will try to investigate it further may be using AOP. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to create totals using the "Actions" menu. But, grand total can't be computed that way (at least, I don't know how).

But, if you modify the query and do everything within, then you'd `group by rollup` and get the result.

This example is based on Scott's sample `emp` table; adjust it so that it contains your columns/table(s):

```
select deptno, 
       ename, 
       sum(sal) sumsal 
from emp
where deptno in (10, 20)
group by rollup (deptno, ename)
order by deptno, ename;
```

The result is then

[image]